# CATextLayer changing text fast

Tags: ios, performance, core-graphics, uilabel, core-text

I am working on an app that needs to change **a lot** of CATextLayers strings, but, only one or two characters of it(in general though, the strings are in length of about 2-5 characters).

At first I went with UILabels which were extremely slow, and because of that I tried out CATextLayer, which was a lot faster, but not fast enough, I am updating about 150 CATextLayers quite often, all at once , and it just doesn't cut it, I feel a lag.

I then tried out to do it even more low-level with CoreText, I tried drawing it with a CTLine, which had about the same performance of CATextLayer, so I got back to the CATextLayers because my positioning code for CoreText wasn't perfect.

I started thinking about caching for each string the first two characters(which are always constant), and only changing the other 3 characters, with smaller bounds, which I assume will be a bit faster, but, will it be faster? After all it will have it to composite it with the other text-layer, and it will have to be update all of the 150 text-layers.

Does anybody have any advice? How would you approach it?

Attached is a screenshot from instruments showing that the problem lies in the performance of CATextLayer: [image: instruments time profile]

Comment: What does Instruments say where the "lag" is? Can you post some Instruments output and the appropriate code?

Comment: @RoboticCat I attached a screenshot

Comment: Hmmmm....I don't know CATextLayer well but it does look like a performance problem - a bit of a surprise but 150 CALayers is quite a lot. If you run the Core Animation Instrument and check for opacity what does it look like? Can you also give us a screenshot of your app?

Comment: What do you mean by check for opacity? I know my app has a lot of non-opaque layers, and I know its hard on the CPU, but it's a must, I'll upload a screenshot as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap Fonts are probably the best way to solve this problem, as they're far and away more performant than anything else in terms of font drawing for something of this nature. But you need to pre-render them to the scale you desire to get the best out of them both visually and in terms of performance.

And you might be best off using Sprite Kit, as it has native handling of them. Here's a github repo with a useful thing to make it easier to use rendered bitmaps from a common tool for creating them:  https://github.com/tapouillo/BMGlyphLabel